# Eclipse juno deployment requires clean and build everytime

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7, eclipse-juno

I have a web application developed in *Eclipse Juno*, I am using *Tomcat 7.0.32* as a web server. When ever I'm doing small changes and deploying the application, changes are not taken by the tomcat.

Under Eclipse tomcat deploy path *wtpwebapps*, I have found the following:

1. Few/all JAR's given in the build path are missing
2. Recently compiled java files are not updated

These things led into *ClassNotFoundException* sometimes and Unexpected functionality sometimes.
So, when I *do clean and build the project* for small changes every time,deployment works fine. But clean and build takes more time

Is it a problem with eclipse deployment plug-in? Help me out to overcome, thanks

Comment: Is your Build Automatically checked ?

Comment: Yes it is set and I checked the class files in the workspace also